# How to override MaterialApp's theme in flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, themes

I am trying to use Theme widget to override theme styling for specific container.

Here I have set body text color white for all my text widgets.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          )
        )
      ),
      initialRoute: Home.id,
      routes: {
        Home.id: (context) => Home()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to set color black for all text widgets inside this container but it is still fetching the white color set at Material app widget.

```
class NewTask extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
                textTheme: TextTheme(
                    bodyText2: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                    )
                )
            ),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "New Task",
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

I was able to make it work by wrapping Container widget inside Builder method and setting

```
TextStyle(
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.color
),
```

but this seems a lot of work if I have multiple text widgets inside this container, I don't understand what is wrong or this is not how theme widget is supposed to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The data from the closest Theme instance that encloses the given context.

*[Theme class docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme/of.html)*

When you call `Theme.of(context)`, you would be referring to the context of `NewTask.build`. The `Theme` object associated with this context will the `MaterialApp.theme`. So, to use the the `ThemeData` provided by your `Theme` widget, you could either use a `Builder` or extract `Theme` and its descendants to a new `StatelessWidget` or if required, `StatefulWidget`

The `Builder` widget essentially wraps its descendants in a `StatelessWidget` and provides the `build` method as a callback.

Comment: I know I can wrap my container inside Builder widget & the context will change. Then I can manually set color using TextStyle widget & the color property value will be
Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.color .
This works fine.
But why do I have to do this? I have already wrapped my container inside Theme widget & the text widget should automatically fetch the color value set at Theme widget.